# Integration test Asp.Net Core attribute parameter modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, integration-testing, endpoint

I've got an endpoint method that has a custom attribute like:

```
[Route ("/version")]
[CacheFilter (hours: 12)]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Version ()
{ ... }
```

And my cache filter sets that specified cache time in its constructor:

```
public CacheFilterAttribute (int days = 0, int hours = 0, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0) : base (typeof (CacheFilter))
{
    this.days = days;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes ...
}
```

I would like to know if when I'm testing that endpoint is any possibility to change that time to (for example) 10 seconds.

I call that endpoint method in my unit test this way:

```
await RADBServer.Client.GetAsync ("/version");
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: unit testing? or integration testing? That attribute is metadata that is only applicable in an actual pipeline at run time. There is no way to change that as it is related to compile time details.

Comment: Yes, integration tests, sorry. I've just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done. For integatrion test, using the testserver just add a global filter to your MVC, your need to implement the IActionFilter. Then on the.OnActionExecuting method you can access the specific method attribute to change its public properties (like the values passed on the attribute constructor). Your method filter will be called after the global filter with the new properties values.

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(typefof(TestFilter))...

{ public class TestFilter : IActionFilter { public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { // obtain the method attributes and change values }
```